# When calculating, the taskbar icon will not change in Mathematica 12.2

Tags: front-end, interface, version-12.2

I remember starting in Mathematica11, when calculating the status of the taskbar can indicate the current status
[image]
Today I upgraded to Mathematica 12.2, I noticed that the taskbar has only one state during calculation.
Can you reproduce this? I am using windows10 20H2.

Comment: Yes, I get this too - I upgraded yesterday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just no longer the default.  You can turn it back on via `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "EvaluationQueueActions"] =  Append[CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "EvaluationQueueActions"], "Icon"]`.

Comment: Can you clarify if this is a method that will change it for all sessions, or just the current one? Can this effectively be done via changes to the preferences/options dialog box?

Comment: @CATrevillian, it will persist between sessions.  It is not present in the Preferences dialog, but you can find it in the Options Inspector.